# Change color of only one current element in the list

Tags: javascript

So I have a list of elements that originally have white backgrounds and my goal is when I click one of it it changes color to blue, but only one element can by chosen and have color - if another element was clicked earlier it background return to white

I was trying with this code to achive my goal - I made variable that is supposed to show if something on the list was clicked before - if yes show true, if not - show false, but when I log it on the console it show that is false since I click the same element on the list twice - then is true

```
var clicked = ""
        table.addEventListener("click",function (event){
            console.log(clicked==true)
            table.style.backgroundColor="blue"
            clicked=true              
        })
    }
```

Comment: You're console logging an evaluation of `clicked` equalling `true` *before* you change the value

Comment: So I moved it on the bootom of the code but still - when I click another element on the list conosle log that clicked is false, so it looks like when I cilck it it start with  not written value of clicked

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/p10eurtx/). Must be another reason, can you post a working snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the table has all the elements in it,

```
        table.addEventListener("click",function (event){
            for (let i = 0;i<table.children.length;i++) {
              table.children[i].style.backgroundColor = "white"
            }
            event.target.style.backgroundColor="blue"           
        })
    }
```

This just makes all of the elements in the tables background color white, then makes the one you clicked on blue, so only one will ever be clicked